# Multiplying in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I need to multiply priceMonthly by 30, How can I do that in this "if" function? I am using it to echo the entered number live , but I need that number to multiply by 30. Dose someone have over ideas, or can someone guide me why its not working ?

```
function keyup_fill(ele, ele_place) {
    $(ele).on("keyup", function(event) {

        if ( $(ele).attr("name") === "priceMonthly" ) {
            if (!$.isNumeric($(ele).val())) {
                return ($(ele).val()*30); //not working
            }
        }

      var newText = event.target.value ;
        $(ele_place).html(newText); 
    });
}


keyup_fill("#priceMonthly", "#priceMonthly-place");
```

Comment: `return` will do nothing there... At least, nothing useful.

Comment: Your function `keyup_fill` isn't actually doing any calculation or returnable action, it's just attaching a `"keyup"` listener to the element. Each time you call `keyup_fill`, you're going to be attaching multiple, duplicate, events. After calling the function, you'll need to type in the `#priceMonthly` box to see the action actually occur.

Comment: Try initializing a variable before the first `if` statement like `let val = 0;`, then instead of returning, set the val variable and before you multiply it by 30, parse it from a string to an int. `val = parseInt($(ele).val()) * 30;`

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to show in `#priceMonthly-place` the result of multiplying by 30 the value entered in `#priceMonthly` you can do this with the code (note that I'm assuming that both ids represent input elements):

```
function keyup_fill(ele, ele_place) {
    $(ele).on("keyup", function(event) {
        // I'm assuming that `ele` is an input.
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
            // I'm assuming that ele_place is an input.
            $(ele_place).val(value * 30);
        }
    });
}

keyup_fill("#priceMonthly", "#priceMonthly-place");
```